# how to improve the magento search - Apache Solr or google search

Tags: search, catalogsearch

I used "Synonym" and " redirection" and using "LIKE AND FULL TEXT" to improve search

i heard about Apache Solr!

and there is an extension for integrating Apache Solr! to magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-bridge-search.html

is this the best solution for search in magento site ?

or is installing google search is better or is any other extension that give best searching in a site.

please give me some tips to improve the search in magento site.